# In C, why don't I get an error when I declare an global variable in different data type in an other file?

Tags: c, extern

I have tried the following code:

File1.c:

```
int x;
```

File2.c:

```
extern char x;
main()
{
    x=10;
    ....
    ....
}
```

and compiled as

$gcc File1.c File2.c

and I didn't get any error but I was expecting one.

Comment: Compile with `-Wall` and see if you get warnings

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are extern variables in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c)

Comment: *With great power comes great responsability*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In `File.c`, you promise to the compiler that `x` is of type `char`. Since every translation unit is compiled separately, the compiler has no way of verifying this, and takes your word for it. And the linker doesn't do any type checking. You end up with an invalid program that builds with no errors.

This is why you should use header files. If `File1.c` and `File2.c` both got an `extern` declaration of `x` from the same header, then you would get an error when compiling `File1.c` (because the definition doesn't match the declaration). [Hat tip @SteveJessop]

Comment: That's it. And, since 10 is both a valid `int` and a valid `char`, compilation works fine.

Comment: Thanks Steve for clarifying that to me..But i got curious and now i initialized the global variable x as char in file1 and declared it as int in file2 and i have put a value of 1000 which char cant handle and to print it..By your explanation now i am expecting an run time error and i did not get one..

Comment: @BillHicks: The behaviour of your code is undefined (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). It does not have to crash or give you a runtime error. It is free to malfunction (or not) in other ways.

Comment: @Fabien: No, compilation works fine because the compiler doesn't know that you are going link the result of compiling File2.c against the rsult of compiling File1.c that defined x as an int.

Comment: @Axel yes, but if, in File2.c, it was defined as, say, an ` extern char*`, the compiler would have complained for that reason.